# Can I wrap an input field with some additional functions when using null coalescing operator in PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7

Let's say I have this trivial example:

```
$foo = $_REQUEST['foo'] ?? '';
```

This works beautifully and doesn't throw a notice with undefined index `foo` when it's not set. Cool. Assuming it's set - **I would like to wrap it with additional methods** like `trim` and `strtolower`.

```
$foo = strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['foo'])) ?? '';
```

Can I do this? Will I get the same result? Will `foo` be trimmed and lower case when exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written will result in an undefined index.

Since strtolower and trim won't make any adjustments to an empty string, you can perform:

```
$foo = strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['foo'] ?? ''));
```

Performing your coalesce on the trim parameter will prevent the undefined $_REQUEST index from being evaluated by the trim function.